# How do I plot a horizontal line and a curve in the same graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, horizontal-line

I'm supposed to show the plot of data (curve) and a plot of the average of the data (flat horizontal line) in the same graph. My code computes everything fine and displays the curve in the graph, but I can't get the horizontal line to show up.

```
plot(1:24,hours3,'b-.',1:24, avg3,'r--');
```

So the plot of the column "hours3" shows up just fine, but the plot of the average "avg3" does not come up at all. It should be a flat line that extends from points 1 to 24 on the x-axis. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `plot(1:24,avg3,rx--)` is interpreted as 24 single points. Using `rx--` as linestyle shows you that the points are plotted right but not connected.

```
plot(1:24,hours3,'b-.',1:24, repmat(avg3,1,24),'r--');
```

Also with `hold on` you can keep plotting in an existing figure.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
StartPoint=1;
EndPoint=24;
Resolution=1; % you can set 0.1 if you want more precision
Ave=Ave3;% set a value for Ave3

x=[StartPoint:Resolution:EndPoint]; 
NumberofPoints=((EndPoint-StartPoint)/Resolution)+1;
HrzLine=Ave*ones(1,NumberofPoints);

Curve=0.2*x.^3-4.*x.^2+8;

plot(x,HrzLine);
hold on;
plot(x,Curve);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2018b release has made adding horizontal lines (& vertical lines) much easier with [`yline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) ([`xline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) for verticle lines).

```
Xrng = 1:.01:24;
fh =@(x) 0.2*x.^3 - 4.*x.^2 + 50*sin(x)+ 8;     % curve

plot(Xrng,fh(Xrng))
yline(0)                                        % horizontal line at y = 0
```

Subsequent lines can be added just as easily.

```
yline(50)                                       % horizontal line at y = 0
xline(12,'b--')                                 % vertical line at x = 12  (blue, dashed)
```

<sub>Requires MATLAB R2018b or later.</sub>